# truncated quantile regression in R

Tags: quantiles, quantile-regression

I have used the "quantreg" package in R to find quantiles for my data. All my data, both predictors and responses are limited between 0 and 1, while a number of quantiles given by "rq" or "rqss" functions have values less than 0 or more than one. I was wondering if there is a solution for this problem, maybe a different function which gives truncated quantiles. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quantile regression is an additive model.  No purely additive linear model can prevent predicted values from going outside any given range.  You can either hope to find a transformation of $Y$ that does not have a limited range that will fit the model, or consider the use of ordinal regression.  For example the R `rms` package `orm` function handles continuous $Y$ and allows estimation of quantiles, the mean, and exceedance probabilities

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the property of equivariance to monotonic transformations, shared by all quantile methods, one can simply operate a logit transformation and run a linear quantile regression on the transformed outcome.

For further information you might consider referring to this paper on quantile regression for bounded outcomes ([Bottai & McKeown 2010](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.3781/abstract;jsessionid=57D1E3B487E24257A7F45A64F224B68E.f02t04)).